# Passing variable from one Makefile to another

Tags: makefile

I have two makefiles in two directories. The test program is compiled with the Makefile, a part of which looks like this:

```
CFLAGS_LOCAL += -I$(ROOT)/dir1 -DPERF_TEST

dir := $(ROOT)/dir1
include $(dir)/dir1.mk
```

The test programs is dependent on files of dir1. I want to compile these files with the flag -DPERF_TEST (only for the particular test program). But unless I explicitly add the flag in dir1.mk it doesn't take effect. I tried:

```
export PERF_TEST = 1
```

But that didn't work either. How do I compile dir1 files with the -PERF_TEST flag for this test program? For other programs and libraries I want dir1 to compile as it is (without the flag).

Comment: You should show us the real content of both makefiles.

Comment: If you have the variable set when you `include` the `dir1.mk` makefile it will be set when that makefile goes to look for it (unless it gets unset later before the contents of `dir1.mk` need it). Are you trying that? How are you using it in `dir1.mk`?

Comment: You seem to want two different versions of certain object files, is that correct? Do you want to store them in two different places? Do you want to give them two different sets of names?

Comment: Thank you all for replying. Another .mk was also included in between and thus resetting the value of CFLAGS_LOCAL. Things are working now.